# сравнить текущее время с указаным временем в базе данных

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

у меня проблема которую не знаю как решить.

у меня есть база данных с таблицей авиарейсов, в которой есть разные атрибуты, в том числе "departure_time". если пользователь хочет купить сегодняшний билет, то ему выведет только те рейсы, которые еще не совершились. например: ввожу направление Рим-Лондон, на сегодня есть рейсы в 10 утра и в 10 вечера, а сейчас 3 часа дня, естественно я не могу полететь по рейсу, который был 5 часов назад, а то есть, этот рейс мне не покажет, но могу полететь через 7 часов и этот рейс мне покажет.
в общем, не знаю как именно отправить запрос в базу, чтобы он сравнивал текущее время со временем отправки самолета и выводил только доступные рейсы.

буду благодарна за любую помощь!

    `<input class="currentTime" type="hidden" name="time">
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getHours() + ':' + (now.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + now.getMinutes();
$cutime = $_REQUEST['time'];
$queryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`flights`WHERE //дальше не знаю что именно прописать");`

Comment: а столбец с датами, какого конкретно типа?

Comment: @Otis666  время time, а вот конкретных дат в базе у меня нет. у меня есть дни недели полета. выбирая дату в календаре, я сразу его перевожу в день и запросом отправляю уже как день недели

Comment: now.getMinutes()<10?'0':'' для чего этот код?

Comment: у вас js-код выдает не корректное время, должно быть так, var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes()+ ":" + now.getSeconds();

Comment: @Otis666 секунды не так важны, поэтому я их не указываю. 
"now.getMinutes()<10?'0'" это для того, чтобы минуты показывало так : 15:08, а не 15:8

Comment: @Otis666 вы не могли бы еще подсказать как сделать так, чтобы показывали рейсы минимум на час раньше. то есть, рейс на 11 утра я не смогу купить, если сейчас 10 часов, а вот в 9:59 еще смогу

Comment: может я туплю, а почему с часами не сделали такой же трюк? я запустил ваш код, а alert мне выдал 3:30, хотя по вашей логике должно быть 03:30

Comment: @Otis666 все правильно, с часами я такого не делала. только с минутами. потому что видеть "3" часа, а не "03", как-то приемлемо, а вот "3" минуты вместо "03" глаза режет

Comment: в общем, если вы хотите чтобы mysql сравнивал ваше время с тем, что в таблице корректно, приведите передаваемое js-кодом время к виду HH:MM:SS, к примеру 03:30:28

Comment: чтобы заказывать за час, передайте серверу время на час меньше, чем реальное, пример: var time = (now.getHours()-1) + ':' + (now.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+":" + now.getMinutes();

Comment: @Otis666 спасибо большое за все

Comment: что заработало?

Comment: @Otis666 ну я в запросе прописала так `departure_time` > (NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR), и все правильно работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE имяСтолбцаВремени > NOW()
```

Comment: пробовала первый вариант раньше,не помогало. а вот уже исправленный подошел. благодарю!

Comment: только в коде один нюанс, NOW() это время на стороне сервера и оно может отличаться от времени на стороне клиента